# How to get the value after a specific amount of dots in a SQL server query result

Tags: sql

I have one of the column data in a table as:

```
123.88568.30959300.001.NBIS.07-28-17.XML
```

From this data I want a value after 3 dot like `001`. The values length will vary. I tried by using substring function but m getting first value only i.e `123`.

Comment: Which database are you using? There may be simpler ways depending on which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

This works for SQL-Server

```sql
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)='123.88568.30959300.001.NBIS.07-28-17.XML'
DECLARE @start int = 0
DECLARE @end int = 0

SET @start = CHARINDEX('.', @str, CHARINDEX('.', @str, CHARINDEX('.', @str)+1)+1) +1
SET @end = CHARINDEX('.', @str, @start)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, @start, @end - @start)
```

In MySQL, you can do this.

```sql
SET @str = "123.885568.309159300.001.NBIS.07-28-17.XML";
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str, ".", 4)), ".", -1);
```

---

<sup>Further reading

- [SQL Server CHARINDEX() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp)

- [SQL Server SUBSTRING() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) 
- [MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp)</sup>